# Como puedo guardar datos en una tabla relacionada utilizando codeigniter

Tags: base-de-datos, codeigniter

necesito insertar datos en una tabla relacionada utilizando el framework de codeigniter y mi duda es como mostrar los datos de las 2 llaves foraneas (no la id si no su valor) y poder insertarlas 
Tabla Ruta (tabla relacionada)

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_rutas` (
  `idRutas` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LugarOrigen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LugarDestino` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRutas`),
  KEY `LugarOrigen` (`LugarOrigen`),
  KEY `LugarDestino` (`LugarDestino`),
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_rutas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LugarOrigen`) REFERENCES `tbl_lugares` (`idlugares`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_rutas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`LugarDestino`) REFERENCES `tbl_lugares` (`idlugares`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

tabla Lugares

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_lugares` (
  `idlugares` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Lugares` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlugares`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

En estos momentos estoy insertando de manera normal

Carpeta controlador Paradas.php

```
<?php  
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

class Paradas extends CI_Controller {  

    public function index()  
    {  
        $this->load->view("Rutas");  
    }  
    function savingdata()  
    {  
        //this array is used to get fetch data from the view page.  
        $data = array(  
                        'LugarOrigen' => $this->input->post('LugarOrigen'),
                        'LugarDestino' => $this->input->post('LugarDestino')
                        );  
        //insert data into database table.  
        $this->db->insert('tbl_rutas',$data);  

        redirect("Paradas/index");  
    }  
}  
?>
```

Carpeta Vista Rutas.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Baby Form Add</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Paradas/savingdata'); ?>">  
        <table>  
            <tr>  
                <td>Origen:</td>  
                <td>:</td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="LugarOrigen"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td>Destino:</td>  
                <td>:</td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="LugarDestino"></td>  
            </tr> 
            <br><br>  
            <tr>  
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

por el momento yo pongo la id para insertar pero quiero mostrar todas los lugares que existen utilizando un combobox

Comment: No se entiende en absoluto tu pregunta, puedes editarla y replantearla detenidamente para que podamos ayudarte, que es lo que esperas hacer y que es lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que lo necesitas es cambiar la forma en que se ingresa los datos en el fromulario por una más amigable.

En ese caso debes modificar el método `index()` para enviar a la vista la lista de lugares. Luego en la vista puedes usar la lista de lugares para llenar un combobox.

Controlador:

```php
public function index()  
{
    //Obtener lista de lugares
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_lugares');
    $lugares = $query->result_array()

    //Carga vista
    $this->load->view("Rutas", array('lugares' => $lugares));  
}
```

Vista:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Paradas/savingdata'); ?>">  
<table>  
    <tr>  
        <td>Origen:</td>  
        <td>:</td>  
        <td>
            <select name="LugarOrigen">
            <?php foreach($lugares as $lugar){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $lugar['idlugares']; ?>"><?php echo $lugar['Lugares']; ?></option>
            <?php }?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>Destino:</td>  
        <td>:</td>  
        <td>
            <select name="LugarDestino">
            <?php foreach($lugares as $lugar){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $lugar['idlugares']; ?>"><?php echo $lugar['Lugares']; ?></option>
            <?php }?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <br><br>  
    <tr>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">  
    </tr>  
</table>
</form>
```

Adémas te recomiendo realizar las consultas a la base de datos en un modelo y no directamente desde el controlador.